# Does loadFactor=0.1 makes HashMap really faster than loadFactor=0.6 or there is some lower bound below which making loadFactor smaller has no sense?

Tags: java, hashmap

Does loadFactor=0.1 makes HashMap really faster than  loadFactor=0.6 or there is some lower bound below which making loadFactor smaller has no sense?

I mean if I do not care about memory consumption - if only speed (put / contains - operations involving finding respective bucket / key(-value)) is important?

There is a common opinion that loadFactor shall be within 0.6 - 0.8, but why I never heard people speak about 0.1, 0.2, 0.05 seriously?..

Comment: No it doesn't. The default value is adequate for most purposes, and using heroic factors like 0.1 won't yield any significant improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The only property of a hashmap that makes it fast is the [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) of the hash function.

The hash function is what we depend upon, to make use of the space given to the hashmap, no matter the size of that space.

Let's look at the cases,

#### Case 1. High load factor

A high load factor will mean the hashmap only rehashes it's keys when the space is almost full. You can see that in this case, the performance will only improve if the hash function is good, otherwise, we will get multiple keys being placed in the same bucket.

#### Case 2. Low load factor

A low load factor means the hashmap will frequently have to allocate memory to keep the key space as wide as possible. Again the performance is determined by the hash function not the space because the hash function has to distribute the keys over this space.

Note that this time around the performance factor is not only a function of how well distributed the keys are, but also of how much space we save with each collision. With lots of space, but very low number of items in that space means that the amount of memory required to store each item (at a minimum) will be `(1 / loadfactor)`. That is if we don't get collisions.

For example, if the hashmap stores bytes and has a total space of `100` bytes, then with a load factor of `0.1`, each `1` byte of storage is equivalent to `10` bytes, and only a maximum of `10` items can be stored before a rehash. However, if a collision occurs, this number increases. So if we get two items colliding, then we only use `9` buckets out of the `10` possible buckets, and as such it turns out that the amount of memory required to store each item is somewhere just above `11` bytes.

---

In the end, I suggest going with what Java has always recommended (0.75). I'm not quite sure how they settled on this value, but it seems to hit the sweet spot of reducing the space cost incurred by collisions (`1.33` bytes per byte), as well as frequency of a rehash.

Again this all points to the hash function - how well it can use the space given to it determines the performance of the hashmap, and also how high we can go with the load factor. The goal after all is a **perfect hash** where load factor is `1` and collision is `0`.

I suggest as an exercise that you implement a hashmap and tweak its load factor, as well as the hash function used, to really get an idea of what works.